# ScreenSaver Application

Tags: ios, screensaver

I need to build an Application, which when the phone stays idle for say 1 minute, or about to lock, we need to open the app as a screen saver.

Also, Is it possible to launch an app without manually doing it and without opening any other apps?

Comment: i dont think that possible in iOS

Comment: Well you could disable the phone's auto-lock and just start displaying a screen save after a minute.

Comment: Sorry but this is not going to be possible.